# Two consecutive adverbs using comma?

Tags: commas, adverbs, lists

Is it proper to use this instance of two consecutive adverbs separated by a comma?

e.g. "He seriously, actually has this problem."

I have seen some consecutive adverbs be okay, but others not.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related and worth a look for a more usual alternative in many cases (using 'and' rather than 'but', as a comment does, thus '... quickly and furtively...'): [Comma usage when 'but' is used between two adjectives or adverbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147655/comma-usage-when-but-is-used-between-two-adjective-or-adverbs). The adverb,adverb structure is probably largely restricted to a literary register.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. The comma stands in for an elided conjunction. From [*The Lodger*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5l5IAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22quickly%20furtively%22&source=bl&ots=NA3SOI2Cae&sig=RADsovPDqIRtnROl3mYsexxHWpk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn8tmM4eDOAhVEziYKHXMaAsYQ6AEILDAE#v=onepage&q=%22quickly%20furtively%22&f=false)
by Marie Belloc Lowndes:

> Again she glanced at him **quickly, furtively**, but he seemed just as
>   usual

Your example is a little odd because while people have serious problems, we usually don't say that they have them seriously, i.e., in a serious way. The sentence also has an echo of an introductory adverb --

> Seriously, he actually has this problem

which means, "I'm serious about his having this problem."

Comment: This is a strange one. _Seriously_ here is certainly the pragmatic usage (an emphasiser by the speaker, as you say) but the sentence sounds odd for a second reason: _actually_ here at least strongly connotes an(other) emphasiser reading. A bare 'He actually has this problem' can have two readings: 'Believe it or not, he has this problem' or the corrective 'This is the problem he actually has [though you / others / many think he has problem Y, Z...). Your example is far less awkward: two proper adverbs.

Comment: Please consider both the cliched question “Do you really, truly love me?” and the obvious answer “Truly, madly, deeply…”

Is there any problem with either example, other than that even the first two, let alone five synonymous adverbs seems unimaginative?

Comment: I've considered it, and I'm afraid I don't. Sorry.